Issue Creating Folder in External Storage with React Native
I'm trying to create a folder in a public location on external storage in a React Native app, but I'm encountering issues. I've set up the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml and I'm requesting storage and camera permissions correctly in the code. However, the folder is not being created.


import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Alert, Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

// Function to request storage permissions
const requestStoragePermissions = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Storage Permission',
          message: 'This app needs permission to access external storage.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

// Function to request camera permissions
const requestCameraPermissions = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'Camera Permission',
          message: 'This app needs permission to access the camera.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

// Function to create a folder in external storage
const createExternalFolder = async () => {
  const hasStoragePermission = await requestStoragePermissions();
  const hasCameraPermission = await requestCameraPermissions();

  if (!hasStoragePermission) {
    Alert.alert('Permission Denied', 'You cannot access external storage.');
    return;
  }

  if (!hasCameraPermission) {
    Alert.alert('Permission Denied', 'You cannot access the camera.');
    return;
  }

  try {
    // Path to the external storage directory
    const externalPath = `${RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath}/MyPublicFolder`;

    console.log('External directory path:', externalPath);

    // Create the folder
    await RNFS.mkdir(externalPath);

    // Check if the folder was created
    const folderExists = await RNFS.exists(externalPath);
    if (folderExists) {
      Alert.alert('Folder Created', `Folder created at: ${externalPath}`);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to create the folder.');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating folder:', err);
    Alert.alert('Error', err.message);
  }
};

const FileExample = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Button title="Create Folder in External Storage" onPress={createExternalFolder} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FileExample;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



In my AndroidManifest.xml, I have the following permissions configured:


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  ...
</manifest>



Despite requesting the permissions and following the steps mentioned, I'm still unable to create the folder. Is there anything I'm missing or any additional steps I should take?
